# Verbal question problem help

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I had this question today and I got confused on how to construct my solution for this. At the first view of the question, I decided to use $X$ and $Y$ and no other option:

Maria purchased $X$ books for 300 dollars. After a day, the shop sold the books for 2 dollars cheaper. So Ana purchased 10 books more than Maria, and each book costed dollar 2 less than the original price. Ana paid 350 for her books.

How many books Maria purchased, and how much each costed?

I structured  my 2 equations like this:

${X \cdot Y = 300}$

$(X + 10) \cdot (Y - 2) = 350$

Did I build my two equations correctly according to the question? How can I solve it? because when I solve it, I get $-Y^2 = 640$ and then I get totally lost not knowing if I did that right.

My steps:

$X = 300 - Y$

$((300 - Y) + 10)(Y - 2) = 350$
$=> (3000 -10Y)(Y - 2) = 350 => 3000Y - 6000 - 10Y^2 - 20Y = 350$

Now idea what to do from this step...

Comment: The second equation should be $(Y-2)(X+10)=350$. $Y$ is the original price and $X$ is the number of books Maria purchased. Although it doesn't really affect how the equation should be solved.

Comment: Yea sorry missed that after translating to englsih

Comment: Could you show your steps for us to find your error?

Comment: Edited now @KittyL

Comment: The first step should be $X=300/Y$.

Comment: How did you get $X=300−Y$.

Comment: @KittyL is right when he mentions $ X=300/Y$.

Comment: dont u divide both sides by X (1)?

Comment: You divide both sides by $X$ or $Y$, but what you did was to subtract $Y$ from both sides.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is in this step: $(X−2)⋅(Y+10)=350$

It should be ideally $(X+10)⋅(Y-2)=350$

The second equation uses the variables appropriately chosen by you and will even give the correct result.

Your step first should be  $X=300/Y$

Comment: It should be $(X+10).(Y-2)=350$

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, the first step should be $X=300/Y$. But that will make it hard to solve. A better way is to look at your second equation. If you multiply it out, there is a term $XY$ which can be replaced with $300$ according to your first equation. You might then go on to do your substitution with this simplified step.

Also you should be careful when doing the algebra. I noticed several mistakes in your steps. For example $(300-Y)+10 \ne 3000 -10Y$, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Maria bought X books for 300 dollars.
So cost of each book $=\frac{300}{X}.$

After that the prices were reduced by 2 dollars per book.

So Ana bought $(X+10)$ books for 350 dollars.

So, cost of each book $=\frac{350}{X+10}.$

According to the problem,

$\frac{300}{X}-2=\frac{350}{X+10}.\\or, \frac{150}{X}-1=\frac{175}{X+10}.\\or,\frac{150}{X}=\frac{175}{X+10}+1.\\or,\frac{150}{X}=\frac{185+X}{X+10}.\\or,150(X+10)=X(185+X).\\or, 150X+1500=185X+X^2.\\or,X^2+35X+1500=0.\\or, (X+60)(X-25)=0.$

This gives either $X=-60$  or  $X=25$ .

Since number of books purchased cannot be negative,  the valid solution is   $X=25$  .
So Maria bought $25$ books and cost of each book was $\frac{300}{25}=12$  dollars .